# Postfix : intercept outgoing email by sender with amavis or custom filter?

Tags: postfix, filtering, amavis

we have some outgoing mail server with latest postfix and amavis.

I would need to intercept some outgoing email for some given senders and forward them to a "logging" account + the regular receivers.

From what I read looks like this job could be only done by a custom filter, since we already have amavis in place I was wondering if this could be done directly by amavis.

Any custom postfix filter example with filtering by sender would be welcome too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most, if not all, of what you want to do can be done with [Sender BCC maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_bcc_maps), and a simple filter on the BCC account, `.procmail` or `sieve` being quite simple ways to do the secondary filtering.

Comment: Cool! Sender BCC maps looks like what I probably need, I'll check it out thanks

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance!